# Azure Devops Progress Report on Dashboards

Tags: testing, azure-devops, dashboard, test-plan

As I would like to see my team information in one place on the Dashboard, is there a way to see the same Progress Report (Test Plans > Progress Report) on an ADO Dashboard.  There are widgets, but I can't seem to find one to give the same information. I have organized my Test Suites Sprint Wise, and the progress reports provide the information I need.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I checked this problem further. For this requirement, it is not supported at the moment.

We recommend that you could submit a suggestion ticket to suggest the feature on:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21.

Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.